# Getting values from elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reviewing my JavaScript and am having trouble figuring this out. Very simple problem to fix I'm sure. My function below will not read the background-color of my selected object.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    #myDiv {
      background-color: red;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <p id="hello">Hello</p>
  </div>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    var hello = document.getElementById('hello');

    btn.addEventListener('click', color);

    function color() {
      var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
      alert(div.style.backgroundColor);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The alert that returns from this code is blank.

This looks very similar to this on the w3school site, but mine will not work.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundcolor4

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ur not adding in straight into the html try putting style="background-color:red"